# Why do TypeScript interfaces not support index signatures while type aliases do?

Tags: typescript

I have a type with a string index signature:

```
declare var result: {
  [key: string]: number;
};
```

Assigning an interface to the type fails:

```
interface IData {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}
declare var data: IData;
result = data; // Error: Type 'IData' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: number; }'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IData'.
```

But assigning a type alias succeeds:

```
type TData = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
};
declare var data1: TData;
result = data1; // [SUCCEED] why?
```

I expected interfaces and type alias to have the same behavior when assigning to a type with an index signature. Why do they actually behave differently?

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W84GcCuEAuAueA3gFDzwDaA1iAJ75rYwCWAdgOYC6+zGAtgEYgYAbiIBfEURbZBAMyhgEASQAiUbFEIl4ULrwHCtfXf0EjRRUJFgJkMeMDU74KxyPRZs8ALz3X8APT+5ABiAIKKADIAosrs2mBgAPYwwCys8NiJ8ADMAHQAjPm5ACzwoWhojKzMPCDMngDCiTwADmqMfIwQjNjU8GgAFolYwPAC8HJdIMBERL0tCAAqquremqRO3CYGpEbwW-pmIpbQcEgoDur5+MuuRO44a5dQ+UIBQWQAygCqDQ1RMTiAHcBtQAPxAA)

Answer (score 2):

redundant, subscribe to this issue, and the spec is out of date

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300