# Why does Typescript throw an error on the interface but not on the type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know why Typescript throws an error when using the interface but works fine with type. Please consider this code:

```js
const fn = (a: { [key: string]: number | string }) => {
  console.log(a)
};

interface FooInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
type FooType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const fooInterface: FooInterface = { id: 1, name: 'name' };
const fooType: FooType = { id: 1, name: 'name' };

fn(fooType);
fn(fooInterface); <-- error here
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKAhgLhgbxgbQGsBTAT22gCcBLMAcwF1swBXAWwCNjKYAfGKrTowAvgEpkAPlwAoGDFCQQAG2IA6ZSDoYxMkQG4ZM2lG5x0wYjABiIEAEkwpyucuz51ACbN2XSofkwdDZiCigaekMRGShSAAcrWxAAFXirFBw5GC8fTm4AmCCQsIi6KKNFaHg7R2dXUJsapzMLdNxs7xgARgAaQuCGgHIi4kHRQ0rYODtUhOwk2ba8HO6%20kexhgbGDIwRUaZS0sUM9g9qWy2OgA)

The Typescript will throw an error with the line `fn(fooInterface);`. It says:

```
Argument of type 'FooInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string | number; }'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'FooInterface'.
```

Why does the error happen and why does it only happen with the interface?

Comment: Probably relevant: [Why do TypeScript interfaces not support index signatures while type aliases do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58408195)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces do not have an implicit index signature, and that's why you can't pass the interface.
If you would add the index signature, the error will disappear:

```
interface FooInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  [a: string]: string | number;
}
```

The reason behind this is that interfaces can be augmented with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), whereas it is not possible with types.

Related issue: [Typescript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)

Comment: In additional: if you pass an object explicitly using spread syntax the error will also disappear: `fn({...fooInterface});`